# Is there a better method of double negating than nesting an \overline within another \overline?

Tags: math-mode

I am creating a flash card for Double Complement Law. My code gets me the desired effect. I am still curious to know if this is the most efficient method of accomplishing this.

```
[$](\overline {\overline{x}})=x[/$]
```

Comment: I would say so, since it is a generic way of writing the complement of some symbol. An alternative would be to define a new command that writes the double complement, but I don't find that "better" or "more efficient".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply define:

```
\newcommand{\doubleol}[1]{\overline{\overline{#1}}}
```

and use `\doubleol{x}` instead `\overline {\overline{x}}` otherwise if you need to have this kind of thing a lot in your document, you find that you waste too much time on typying and obviously sometimes it may produce error (e.g. you forgot to put one `}` or instead `}`, you put `]`)

Comment: I am assuming that I can add this to the header. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you can put it in the preamble of your document (between `\documentclass{...}` and `\begin{document}`)